# How would one integrate an irreducible fraction using complex numbers?

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

Suppose one wants to integrate $(x^2+1)^{-1}$ using complex numbers instead of the typical way.

$(x^2+1)^{-1}$ can be factored into $\frac{1}{(x+i)(x-i)}$ and then into $0.5 i \left(\frac{1}{x+i}-\frac{1}{x-i}\right)$ which seems to result in some thing like $0.5 i \ln \left\lvert{\frac{x+i}{x-i}}\right\rvert$ which doesn't seem right at all.

Comment: Through basic complex algebra, there is a (complex) identity that actually links up your result with the arctangent. It did once exactly your problem for fun but can't find it. But your answer is not incorrect.

Comment: I don't think you want your absolute value anymore, you might be able to start with what the log of a complex number is, based on $log(z e^{i\theta}) = log z + i\theta$

Comment: how about this then, evaluate your integral from 0 to 1, then multiply it by 4 to get $\pi$   https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4*%280.5+*+i++*+%28log%281+%2F+%281+%2B+i%29%29++-+log%281+%2F+%28+1+-+i%29%29%29+-+0.5+*+i++*+%28log%281+%2F+%280+%2B+i%29%29++-+log%281+%2F+%280+-+i%29%29%29%29

Comment: anyway, I seemed to get that 4 times your integral from 0 to 1 was $-\pi$ - I think you did drop a minus sign in the partial fraction- the integral from 0 to 1 should indeed be $\pi/4$

Comment: if you copy my url carefully, you should see the answer

Comment: Take out the absolute value symbol :$(i/2)\log ((x+i)/(x-i))$. Some restrictions apply to the domain but it's still $\tan^{-1}x$ .

Answer (score 0):

here you can see that the term you created can be evaluated over 0 to 1 to give the value $-\pi/4$

[image: -pi]

so you do need the absolute value sign I think, I can't see why it is negative